# Security implication of disclosing composer.lock?

Tags: web-application, php

What are the security implications in disclosing the `composer.lock` file for a remote, public known, web application?

Comment: I think this falls under the same category of any disclosure of specific versions of software used on a server ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As composer can describe the

> exact version numbers, and are useful to communicate the version you tested with to colleagues or when publishing an application

[Reference #1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10677536/3993770)

Revealing the version of the underlying library can be used against the application.

> composer.lock file also ensures consistency across clusters of servers

It will ensure that all the servers behind a Load balance will be evenly vulnerable which will make the exploit more stable against a target.

[Reference #2](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/composer-its-all-about-the-lock-file)